# Run two instances of a react application using OAuth2 in the same browser

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, local-storage, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I have two applications using the same authentication and authorization service.
App one is for user management(can only be accessed by the system administrator), and App 2 is for performing tasks and can only be accessed by users added by the system administrator in App one. The system administrator cannot access App two.
When I sign into App one, and later try to sign in to app two in the same browser, I am not able to because the access token for the user in App one is in the local storage, so I need to first sign out of App one, then sign into App two.
How can I sign into both the applications using the same browser?? I am using oidc-client.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it did. I could apply both solutions, but the alternative solution was more helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your provider to give you an access token with multiple audience claims (App1 + App2) , in this way, when you login you can access both applications using the same access token.

An alternative solution is that some providers do provide so that you can get multiple access tokens from a single login. An example of this can be read about here [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/fundamentals/resources/isolation/)